# Is consumer.createMessageStreams(map) method read sequentially or read in some sort of batch

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am very new to kafka. We are writing consumer in our current application, which consumes from a topic and have some processing of data that is consumed. I want to understand, what happens internally when I write below piece of code .

It is working as expected, consuming data and getting processed but just curious to know about how data is been read from a topic.

Will createMessageStreams method reads data sequentially from a topic or it reads in a particular number of batch and process them ?

```
Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumer.createMessageStreams(map);
List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> streams = consumerMap.get(topic);
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, would mention that `ConsumerConnector` or `kafka.consumer.KafkaStream` classes are deprecated in kafka v#0.11.0 version. In case, if you are using old version, you should plan to upgrade to newer version atleast v#1.0 or more.

> Will createMessageStreams method reads data sequentially from a topic
>   or it reads in a particular number of batch and process them ?

`.createMessageStreams` returns a map  of topic and list of KafkaStream pair. `(topic,list#stream)` Each stream supports the iterator over messages or metadata pair for a topic. It reads data sequentially only within the partition. If you have more partitions than the number of stream thread, one thread can read from multiple partition. But only within the partitions, sequence order is guaranteed.

```
  for (final KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> stream : streamList) 
    {
       ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it= stream.iterator();
       while (it.hasNext()) 
       {
          String message = new String(it.next().message());
          System.out.println(message);
        }
      }
}
```

Equivalent functionality in v#0.11 onwards is `.poll()` method. You can set `max.poll.records` or `max.poll.interval.ms` to set the number of records per poll request and interval duration respectively.

You can find the new consumer here:
https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html